# Codigenator active record count_all_results()

Tags: database, codeigniter

This is my query.

```
$this->db->where( 'user_id',$this->session->userdata('id'));
 $this->db->from('votes');
$user_voted = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

i want get user record from table but count_all_results(); not count from table. Any one tell me solution. if my query is not correct.

Comment: TRY this : $num_results = $this->db->count_all_results();

Comment: @ankitsuthar not working. show error.

Comment: $this->db->count_all_results() replaces $this->db->get() in a database call.

Comment: @ankitsuthar . this error show.
Error Number: 1096

No tables used

SELECT *

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/vote/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: This will not work. As noted below only COUNT(*) or COUNT(table.field) work.

I think you need to specify which table you are using COUNT(*) on, so change it to something like COUNT(votes.*)

Comment: thats not because of `count_all_results`. try using `get_compiled_select` instead to see your query and probably you have some syntax/logical error there

Comment: @ankitsuthar i just use 1 table where user_id and session id check. this user already vote or not.

Comment: here you want the user who voted. Ok. one or more result might come. then you give the column mane from which you want and then where & get the result set.

Answer (score 1):

$this->db->count_all_results() replaces $this->db->get() in a database call.

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where($your_conditions);
$num_results = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

And for the actual query (which you should already have):

```
$this->db->select($your_columns);
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where($your_conditions);
$this->db->limit($limit);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

OR you can TRY this:

```
$this->db->from(....);
$this->db->where(....);
$db_results = $this->get();

$results = $db_results->result();
$num_rows = $db_results->num_rows();
```

Try this also:

```
$id = $this->session->userdata('id');

$query = $this->db
                  ->select(column one, column two)
                  ->where('user_id',$id)
                  ->get('votes');
$rowcount = $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: It could solve the problem but if data set be huge, also will use memory much more than `COUNT`

Comment: Maybe but I don't see this happen here. so we hope for the best.

Comment: @ankitsuthar not get result. same error show. i don't know why query not working. every thing is perfect. just i get result from votes table that this user is not voted already.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$this->db->select('COUNT(*) as total');
    $this->db->where('where', 0); 
   $query =  $this->db->get('table');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this for the rows or count:

```
$id=$this->session->userdata('id');
// num rows example
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('user_id',$id);
$query = $this->db->get('votes');
$num = $query->num_rows();
// here you can do something with $query

// count all example
$this->db->where('user_id',$id);
$num = $this->db->count_all_results('votes');
// here you only have $num, no $query
```